# Determine most important sentences of a text

Tags: nlp, text-processing, levenshtein-distance, summarization

I am working on a tool that will allow users to summarize a selected text.

I want to do this by determining x amount of most important sentences of the text (decided by the user/calculated based on text length), and then for each of those "core sentences", I want to accompany the sentence by x amount of most related/similar sentences to that core sentence. That way, I hope to cover multiple important pieces of a text in a few lines, rather than one big piece (subject) of the text. I am aware that not every text will have multiple subjects available to sufficiently have multiple core sentences, the amount of core sentences and related sentences will depend on the text itself.

For determining these important sentences I have currently based myself on the example of [this guide](https://thetokenizer.com/2013/04/28/build-your-own-summary-tool/), which uses intersection scores between sentences to rank each sentence of the text. So far this has lead to decent results, but sometimes the results aren't as qualitative.

Therefore, I am looking for other methods to extract the most important sentences. After a bit of searching, the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) popped up several times as a way to compare strings.

Could I use the **Levenshtein distance**  to calculate the LD between each sentence and add the total LD-amount for each sentence, returning the x amount of sentences with the lowest aggregated Levenshtein distance number - would this result in a representative ranking of the most important sentences of the text?

If not, should I stick to the intersection method or should I consider an alternative?

I am also considering using [tf–idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to "preprocess" a sentence in order to only keep valuable words in the text's sentences.